# How to take user input in JS and assign to a local object, push to a global, and then print to a section of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on my first JS app and am having problems taking a user input, adding it to a local object inside a function, pushing that into a global function upon click event, and printing that to a section of HTML. I am getting undefined on my console.log. I assume it has something to do with the original local object array pulling the user input values as the object values, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
let expensesNew = [];

const addExpense = (ev) => {
  let expense = [{
    name: document.querySelector("[name=expense_Name]").value,
    amount: document.querySelector("[name=expense_Value]").value
  }]
  expensesNew.push(expense);
  for (let i = 0; i < expense.length; i++) {
    console.log(expensesNew.name);
    console.log(expensesNew.amount);
  }
  console.warn('added', {
    expensesNew
  });

  document.querySelector('#title_Expenses').innerHTML = expensesNew[i].name;
  document.querySelector('#value_Expenses').innerHTML = expensesNew[i].amount;
  let message = `You've just added ${expensesNew.name} for ${expensesNew.amount}.`;
  console.log(message);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Budget Application</h1>
  <div id="inputSections" class="inputSections">
    <section id="incomingMoney">
      <h3>Please Enter Your Budget</h3>
      <input type="number" id="incomingCashInput" class="inputs" name="incoming_Cash_Input"><br>
      <button id="incomingCalcButton">Calculate</button>
    </section>

    <section id="enterExpenses">
      <h3>Please Enter Your Expense</h3>
      <input type="text" id="expenseName" class="inputs" name="expense_Name">
      <h3>Please Enter Expense Amount</h3>
      <input type="number" id="expenseAmount" class="inputs" name="expense_Value"><br>
      <button id="expenseButton">Add Expense</button>
    </section>
  </div>
  <section id="calculations" class="calcs">
    <div class="budget calcs">
      <h3>Budget</h3><br>
      <img src="money_icon.png" class="moneyIcon calcIcon"><br>
      <section id="budgetIncoming">

      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="expenses calcs">
      <h3>Expenses</h3><br>
      <img src="expense_icon.png" class="expenseIcon calcIcon"><br>
      <section id="expenseIncoming">

      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="balance calcs">
      <h3>Balance</h3><br><br>
      <img src="budget_icon.png" class="budgetIcon calcIcon"><br>
      <section id="balanceIncoming">

      </section>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="expenses expContainer">
    <div class="expContainer">
      <h4>Expense Title</h4>
      <section class="titleExpenses expContainer" id="title_Expenses">

      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="expContainer">
      <h4>Expense Value</h4><br><br>
      <section class="valueExpenses" id="value_Expenses">

      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="expContainer">
      <h4>Edit</h4>
      <section class="deleteExpenses">

      </section>
    </div>

  </section>


</body>
```

Comment: At the moment, nothing in your example calls the `addExpense` function. If possible, please make sure the code in the question reproduces the problem.

Comment: You're getting `undefined` because you are not accessing the index of `expensesNew` in your loop, and you are also nesting all new expenses in their own array. You would need to call `console.log(expensesNew[i][0].name);`.

Comment: @DBS my mistake, I forgot to put this on there.    
    
```
let outgoingCalcButton = document.getElementById('expenseButton');
expenseButton.addEventListener("click", addExpense);
```

Comment: @pilchard I figured nesting those in an object and pushing them to the main global object (since I will need to use that object with my budget calculations later in another function) to be written into my HTML would be easiest. Is this not the case?